# Kentico 9 WHERE Condition on a repeater sanity check

Tags: kentico

I have a repeater pulling events. I only want to show event for today, and in the future. Is this correct?

```
EventStart >= '{% DateTime.Now #%}'
```

I have the other settings correct, but I think i read this as the star date is less than or equal to today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for events for today and beyond, you need to check something like this:

```
EventStart >= '{% CurrentDateTime.Month.ToString() + "/" + CurrentDateTime.Day.ToString() + "/" + CurrentDateTime.Year.ToString() #%}'
```

If you use `Now` it will return the current time as well.  If you use just a straight date, then it will assume starting at the current day at midnight.

If you want to check for events from the time the page loads, use what you have in your post.